# Does Sitecore cache overlap?

Tags: caching

As I understand, Sitecore tries to find if an item is available in the cache. If it's found in that level, it will return without proceeding further, in the following order :

```
Item Cache => Data Cache => Prefetch Cache
```

I would like to understand if the cache does overlap each other.

If an item is available in the Prefetch Cache, will it be still populated to the Data Cache, and then the Item Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Data Cache** stored items of the Sitecore class ItemInformation.

Its main functionality is to reduce the number of requests to the database. It get filled-in whenever they are requested.

The process for it to get populated is when fetching item from the Prefetch Cache. In other words, the Prefetch Cache fills the Data Cache.

Please have a look here: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/05/07/sitecore-cache/